# lift what is the difference \ and \\ operators when parsing json

Tags: lift, lift-json

using net.liftweb.json what is the difference  \ and \ operators when parsing json ?

```
import net.liftweb.json._
 val parsed = JsonParser.parse(jsonString)
 val name = parsed.\("firstName")
 val userId = parsed.\\("userId")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\\" will extract the value even if it's present within nested json whereas "\" will extract the value only if present as a top-level attribute.

Consider this json

```
 val json = """{"nested1":{"nested2": {"myKey":"myValue"}}}"""
 val jsonMsg = parse(json)
```

In this case

```
 (jsonMsg \ "myKey").values
```

retruns None

where as

```
 (jsonMsg \\ "myKey").values
```

returns myValue